# Windows 10 Language Pack

Tags: windows-10

Good day,

I tried all ways to install Russian Language Pack on Windows 10.
It shows that there is no language pack for tis version.
If I try to install it manually, it shows that update (lp) doesn't fit to this system. I use Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. Need right version for Windows 10 with your subversion!